# Galois theory: Gauss-Wantzel theorem, proof explanation

Tags: galois-theory, proof-explanation, minimal-polynomials, roots-of-unity, geometric-construction

I am using Ian Stewart Galois theory book

and it says

1. that for $A = $ primitive $p^2$ root of unity
   $A$ has min poly of $m(t)= 1+ t^p +.....+t^{p(p-1)}$
   and so $p(p-1)$ is a power of two. why is this so?
2. if $p^k$ -sided regular polygon is constructive, then so must $p^2$ - sided regular polygon, for $k \ge 2$. why is this so?

Comment: I edited your post to make the $\LaTeX$ work.  Remember, "\$" and $\{ \cdot \}$ are your two best friends in $\LaTeX$.  Cheers!

Comment: Did you show that $\Phi_p(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{p-1} t^n$ [is the minimal polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial) of $\zeta_p$ ?

Comment: 1. It can’t be that $p(p-1)$ is a power of $2$: Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic says that in that case, both $p$ and $p-1$ would be powers of $2$. Unless $p-1$=1, of course. For 2, note that not even the $9$-sided regular polygon is constructible.